# Read pdf from jar file

Tags: java, pdf, jar

Good day

I am trying to read a pdf file from my jar file using getClass().getResource ("/file.pdf").

This is my code:

```
try {                         
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(getClass().getResource("/Files/file.pdf").toURI()));
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
} catch(IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code is working fine when I run from netbeans but once packaged, it doesn't. Do you have any idea why this is happening? I thought using the method above resolves the problem with file paths.

Comment: Well what are you trying to do with it, and have you double-checked that the file is actually in the jar file? What happens when you try it? Basically there isn't enough information for us to help you yet.

Comment: If "packaged" means "WAR file", and the JAR is in WEB-INF/lib, try  getResourceAsStream() from the HTTP context.

Comment: I just want the user to view the file. I cannot even call my compiled html help file. The files are saved in my src folder within my project folder. Like I said everything works fine when I use netbeans, but once packaged into a jar file, nothing happens. When I click the button to open the file, nothing happens

Comment: @user3661160: We have no idea what you're doing with the result of the call. We're missing a *lot* of context - and you haven't answered my questions.

Comment: Ill edit  my question just now.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to package my java application with my help file file and other pdf files, so that i can call them from my application regardless of where the application is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out.  I created a folder named "resources" and placed all my pdfs and help file within it.
In my code I used the file directory function to read the files instead of the getResourceAsStream ().